# How to use inequalities in "iif" within a query in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box on one of my forms which returns a number, I am using this number in as criteria for a field in a query, however if no option in the combo box has been selected I want to use a default set of criteria, but access keeps telling me I have invalid syntax. Could someone tell me how I could do this?

`IIf(IsNull([Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b]),<2 or >3,[Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b])`

The problem occurs when I use `<2 or >3` in the middle of the if statement.

Comment: What is your default set of criteria, which you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two part. First of all, here's a pseudo IIF statement to help you understand how they work:

```
IIF(IsNull(SomeFieldOrControl),ConditionIsTrueSoDoThis,ConditionIsFalseSoDoThis)
```

Another way to explain this is with this example where we'll show a zero length string if cmbo_b is null:

This would show a zero length string if cbmo_b is null:

```
IIF(IsNull([Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b]),"",[Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b])
```

I think you need to switch your IsNull function to the Nz (null to zero) function.

For the second part, when it comes to evaluating a two part condition you usually need to surround it with parenthesis, something like this. I really don't think this will work but it's the only thing I can think of trying if you insist on trying to evaluate two different possibilities at once. I've set this up to show 0 if the condition evaluates to true. I'm really not sure what you want to display if the statement is true since you weren't using the IIF function correctly to begin with.

```
IIF(Nz([Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b],0)(<2 or >3),0,[Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b])
```

I am left wondering why you wouldn't just check to see if the condition = 3 since that is apparently what you are evaluating for in a round about way. Just what to show if the condition is found to be true, I'm still not sure since your code doesn't give any clues:

```
IIF(Nz([Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b],0)=3,0,[Forms]![frm_a]![cmbo_b])
```

For a final word, this might be a matter of personal preference but I try to stay away from referencing controls on other forms unless there is just no way around it. Code like this tends to be very fragile since renaming a form or control, or simply making the form a subform will all cause your code to fail and/or error. It's not that it's completely incorrect, it's just that I try to stick with code that is easy to read and as maintainable as possible.

What I do often do is create public functions on forms or subforms and then call them using statements like this:

```
Call Forms("frm_a").MyPublicFunctionName()
```

or

```
Call Me.Parent.MyPublicFunctionName() 'Call function on main form from subform
```

or

```
Call Me.subform1.Form.MyPublicFunctionName() 'Call function on subform
```

Once again, I think this might just be a matter of personal preference. Public functions such as this are difficult to debug because if any error occurs inside MyPublicFunctionName your code will stop on the above line and you won't know which line is actually causing the problem.